# Deleting a record then selecting within the same Spring Transaction still returns the deleted record

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hystrix

I have some code within a spring transaction with the isolation level set to SERIALIZABLE. This code does a few things firstly it deletes all records from a table that have a flag set, next it performs a select to ensure invalid records can not be written and finally the new records are written.

The problem is that the select continues to return the records that were deleted if the code is run with the transaction annotation. My understanding is that because we are performing these operations within the same spring transaction that the previous delete operation will be considered when performing the select.

We are using Spring Boot 2.1 and Hibernate 5.2

A summary of the code is shown below:

```
@HystrixCommand
public void deleteRecord(EntityObj entityObj) {
    fooRepository.deleteById(entityObj.getId());
    //Below line added as part of debugging but I don't think I should really need it?
    fooRepository.flush();
}


public List<EntityObj> findRecordByProperty(final String property) {
    return fooRepository.findEntityObjByProperty(property);
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void debugReadWrite() {

    EntitiyObject entitiyObject = new EntityObject();
    entitiyObject.setId(1);
    deleteRecord(entitiyObject);
    List<EntityObj> results = findRecordByProperty("bar");
    if (!results.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Should be no results!")
    }
}
```

Comment: `.flush()` should fix your issue.

Comment: The transaction has not committed yet, you need to complete the transaction and then find the record. This can be done with two methods with a REQUIRES_NEW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was due to our use of Hystrix. The transaction is started outside of Hystirx and then at a later point goes through a Hystrix command. The Hystrix command is using a threadpool and so the transaction is lost while executing on the new thread from the Hystrix threadpool. See this github issue for more info:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1381

Comment: Please update your question to include Hystrix and a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

The transaction has not committed yet, you need to complete the transaction and then find the record.

decorating the deleteRecord with propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) should solve the issue

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void deleteRecord(EntityObj entityObj) {
    fooRepository.deleteById(entityObj.getId());
    // flush not needed fooRepository.flush();
}
```

A flush is not needed because when deleteRecord completes the translation will be committed.

under the hood

```
//start transaction
public void deleteRecord(EntityObj entityObj) {

    fooRepository.deleteById(entityObj.getId());

}
//commit transaction
```